# Behavior of the 'contains' function in Java

Tags: java, contains

I'm debugging my code and it looks like the built-in function `contains` does not work properly in my case. Look:

```
List<Integer[]> allVariables = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
Integer[] cols = {1};
```

The List contains values:

```
[0] = Integer[1] => {1}
[1] = Integer[4] => {1,2,3,4}
```

So, the following IF expression must be TRUE, but it's false:

```
if (allVariables.contains(cols[0])) {
    //...
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contains is only going to look for the type that the list actually represents.

So if you have a list of `Integer[]`, you are not going to be able to *ever* pass in an `int` and get a `true` result (since `int` cannot be `null`).

To do that you'd have to do a deep search yourself:

```
for(Integer[] arr : allVariables) {
    for(Integer i : arr) {
        if(i != null && i.equals(searchValue)) return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

The list contains `Integer[]` objects, so if you ask it whether it contains `cols` it will return `true`. However, it does not contain each of the individual array elements.

If you want to use contains for each of the elements of those arrays, you should add each element of the array to the list instead of the array itself (for example by using `Collections#addAll` )

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of `Integer[]` instead of `List<Integer>`. This is where the problem lies. When you do a comparison you ask if `Integer x = 1` equals `Integer[] y = {1}`;

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are mutable and as such are only equal if they are the same array. (Not based on their contents) If you want to compare the contents you can need to use a `List<Integer>`

Also you can't compare an element with an array, they will never be equal.

Try the following

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<List<Integer>> allVariables = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    allVariables.add(Arrays.asList(1));
    allVariables.add(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));

    testContains(allVariables, 1);
    testContains(allVariables, 1, 2);
    testContains(allVariables, 1, 2, 3);
    testContains(allVariables, 1, 2, 3, 4);
}

private static void testContains(List<List<Integer>> allVariables, Integer... ints) {
    List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(ints);
    System.out.println("allVariables contains " + intList +
                       " is " + allVariables.contains(intList));
}
```

prints

```
allVariables contains [1] is true
allVariables contains [1, 2] is false
allVariables contains [1, 2, 3] is false
allVariables contains [1, 2, 3, 4] is true
```

Answer (score 1):

Contains seeks objects by reference - not by values. You have two different arrays with the same value - {1}

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29

Your collection contains arrays, not integers. So contains method checks for arrays. Your check should be if (allVariables.contains(cols)), or, if you want to check for integer value, you need to iterate throught all arrays in the list and check in them sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

`cols[0]` is an `Integer`, not an `Integer[]`, which is the element type of your list. So it is only to be expected that `contains` won't find a match. A single-element array is not equal to its single element - they are distinct objects of different types.

Answer (score 0):

In java cols[0] is very different from cols. In C/C++ they are same.
By cols[0] you are refering to first element in Integer[]. Try printing values of cols[0] and cols and you can find the difference.

The behaviour shown by java api is perfert in your case. Since cols[0] will always return 1, which is what you have in your Integer[]. But 1 as integer is not available in arraylist. So, it always gives false.